# How to implement the following desired Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I want to create 2 level deep nested hashmap to represent the types of books stored at each library and a method that updates the data structure when needed.The first level keys are distinct library names, while the 2nd level keys are the following ("default", "waitlisted", "checkedout"). Then each of those keys will point to its value(an Arraylist containing the appropriate book instances). I am having issues instantiating the initial empty nested hashmap and developing a method to further update it.

```
 public static void iterate(HashMap<String, Object> map, String branchname, String itemtype, Item item_instance) {
                for (HashMap.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
//                    System.out.println("Key is:"+ entry.getKey());
                    if (entry.containsKey(branch)){


                    }else{
                        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> temp = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>;
                        temp.put(BORROWED, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        temp.put(WAITLISTED, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        temp.put(DEFAULT, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        entry.put(branch, temp);


                    }




                    if (entry.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                        System.out.println("Map object found, iterating again");
                        iterate((Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("found end , value is:"+ entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know the code above won't run because i tried calling map methods on a hashmap. But the main take away is if the branch string doesn't already exist as a key in the 1st level:

```
if (entry.containsKey(branch)){


                    }else{
                        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> temp = new  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>;
                        temp.put(BORROWED, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        temp.put(WAITLISTED, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        temp.put(DEFAULT, new ArrayList<Item>());
                        entry.put(branch, temp);


                    }
```

create a template for the 2nd layer of the nested hashmap and insert accordingly
***only valid keys for 2nd level are

```
String BORROWED = "borrowed";
String WAITLISTED = "waitlisted";
String DEFAULT = "default";
```

Comment: *I want to create 2 level deep nested hashmap to represent the types of books stored at each library* Please don't. Java has user defined types (objects); create a library type to represent the types of books stored at each library. Or a book type. Nesting things into a hashmap is not required, nor is it a good idea.

Comment: What Elliott Frisch said, plus: Do not use string constants, learn to use Java’s powerful, flexible, and simple [enum facility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead.